# Pagination at App\View\Cell CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp-3.1

How I can use Pagination at App\View\Cell CakePHP3?

I have tried use it like component,and directly.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: for version => 3.5 please take a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213707/use-paginatorhelper-in-cells-cakephp-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From support I get information, that Pagination will not work at View\Cell

Answer (score 0):

Cell does not support component.

That is.