# Use PaginatorHelper in Cells CakePhp 3

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm trying to use Paginator within a Cell the Paginator works rigth but the PaginatorHelper in the Template of the cell just doesn't work.

I'm using CakePhp 3.5

Here is my code

src/View/Cell/FinderCell.php

```
namespace App\View\Cell;
use Cake\View\Cell;
use Cake\Datasource\Paginator;
class FinderCell extends Cell {

    public function display() {
        $this->loadModel('Pokemon');
        $paginador = new Paginator();

        $pokemons = $paginador->paginate(
            $this->Pokemon->find()
        );

        $this->set(compact('pokemons'));
    }
}
```

src/Template/Cell/Finder/display.ctp

```
<?php 
foreach ($pokemons as $pokemon) :
 ?>
<div class="tipo form large-2 medium-2 columns content">
    <?php echo $this->Html->image($pokemon->pokemon_image) ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="paginator">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?= $this->Paginator->prev('<< Anterior') ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->next('Siguiente >>') ?>
    </ul>
    <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
</div>
```

I get this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the helper, then you need to populate either the request object with the pagination parameters, which is what the paginator component would normally do for you:

```
// ...

$this->request = $this->request->withParam(
    'paging',
    $paginator->getPagingParams() + (array)$this->request->getParam('paging')
);

$this->set(compact('pokemons'));
```

or the paginator helper, which in turn sets the parameters on the request object:

```
// ...

$pagingParams = $paginator->getPagingParams();

$this->set(compact('pokemons', 'pagingParams'));
```

```
$this->Paginator->options(['paging' => $pagingParams]);
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\PaginatorInterface::getPagingParams()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Datasource.PaginatorInterface.html#_getPagingParams)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::options()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.Helper.PaginatorHelper.html#_options)**